# CollapsingToolbarLayout with recylerview inside NestedScrollView not works

Tags: android, xml

I have base layout something like this

base_layout.xml

```
     <AppBarLayout>

          <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
               <!-- Collapsed view goes here -->
          </CollapsingToolbarLayout>

     </AppBarLayout>

    <ViewPager>
          <!-- Scrolling things goes here -->
    </ViewPager>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

And 2 child layout which are, 
viewpager_child_1_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout>

     <RecyclerView>  
          <!-- Vertical orientation -->
     </RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and viewpager_child_2_layout.xml

```
<NestedScrollView>

     <LinearLayout>  
          <RelativeLayout>
             <RecyclerView> <!-- Horizontal orientation --> </RecyclerView>
          </RelativeLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout>  
          <RelativeLayout>
              <RecyclerView> <!-- Horizontal orientation --> </RecyclerView>
          </RelativeLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

</NestedScrollView>
```

For **`viewpager_child_1_layout.xml`**, the CollapsingToolbarLayout works as expected, collapse and expand well.

**BUT, it's not happened in `viewpager_child_2_layout.xml`.**

Please help. Thanks.